# Reading and Concat'ing lines until specific value found in Perl

Tags: perl, syslog

Morning SO,

I'm working on redesigning a Perl script designed by an external software vendor. It uses Perl, which I've never written in before. Basically all it does is read a line in, and then send a syslog packet to the a destination host containing that line. I need to modify it so Perl will keep reading and concat'ing until it reaches "". The problem is, it loops on the first line of a given file, and therefore never reaches the send stage. Any guidance on this? I went back and read the original script again, and it doesn't look to have a mechanism for iterating through each line.

**Edit: OK - so apparently I've gone stupid and can't understand basic iterative logic. Fixed the looping problem, now to fix the syslog sending problem.** It reads the data in correctly, but never executes the syslog send request, which implies it's not getting into the if statements.

Program should eventually enter here: if($lineRead eq $check){//do something;}

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use warnings;

use lib qw(.);
use lib qw(<removed>);

use Syslog;
use Time::HiRes qw( time sleep usleep );
use Getopt::Std;

# create log entries at a fixed rate (n per sec)
# Option defautls

my $me = $0;
$me =~ s|.*/||;

my %options = (
        d       =>      "127.0.0.1",     # host
        p       =>      514,             # port
        f       =>      "readme.syslog", # filename
        b       =>      0,               # burst
        v       =>      0,               # verbose
        t       =>      0,               # tcp vs. udp
        l       =>      0,               # loop option
#       u       =>      "127.0.0.2",     # new IP to send
);

my $theProto='tcp';

# Help
sub HELP_MESSAGE {
        print <<EOF;
$me [-d <host>] [-p <port>] [-f filename] [-u <IP>] [-l] [-t] [-b] [-n NAME] [-v] <messages per second>
Options:
-d : destination syslog host (default 127.0.0.1)
-p : destination port (default 514)
-f : filename to read (default readme.syslog)
-b : burst the same message for 20% of the delay time
-t : use TCP instead of UDP for sending syslogs
-v : verbose, display lines read in from file
-n : use NAME for object name in syslog header
-l : loop indefinately
-u : use this IP as spoofed sender (default is NOT to send IP header)
EOF
}

getopts('vbtlu:d:p:n:f:', \%options);

unless (@ARGV) {
        print STDERR "Need an event rate.\n";
        HELP_MESSAGE;
        exit 1;
}

my $nmsg = shift @ARGV;

if (!($nmsg =~ /^\d+$/)) {
        print "Invalid number of messages per second.\n";
        HELP_MESSAGE;
        exit 1;
}

if ($options{t}) { $theProto='tcp'; }

my $syslog = new Syslog(
        name     => $options{n},        # prog name for syslog header
        facility => 'local6',
        priority => 'info',
        loghost  => $options{d},
        port     => $options{p},
        proto    => $theProto,
);

sub doitall() { # for purpose of infinate looping

open(F,$options{f}) or die("Unable to open file: $options{f}\n");

print STDERR "generating $nmsg messages per second to $options{d}:$options{p}\n";
print STDERR "Ctrl-c to stop\n";

# delay in milliseconds
my $delay = 1.0/$nmsg;
my $resolution = 0.2;
my $burst = $nmsg * $resolution;

my $check = "</Event>";
my $lineRead;
my $payload="a";
if ($options{b}) {
    print "Sending $burst messages every ", int ($delay * 1000), "ms\n";
}

while (<F>) {
        #print $lineRead;
        if ($options{v}) {
            print "Read in: $_\n";
        }
        $lineRead=$_;
        if($lineRead eq $check){
                $payload = join $payload, $lineRead;
                if ($options{b}) {
                    for (my $i = 0 ; $i < $burst; $i++) {
                        if ($options{u}) { print $payload; $syslog->send($payload, host=> $options{u}); }
                        else { print $payload; $syslog->send($payload); }
                 }
                } else {
                 if ($options{u}) { print $payload; $syslog->send($payload, host=> $options{u}); }
                 else { print $payload; $syslog->send($payload); }
                }
                if ($delay > 0) {
                        if ($options{v}) {
                            print "waiting for ", int($delay * 1000), "ms ...\n";
                        }
                        usleep (1000000*$delay);
                }
                $lineRead = "a";
                $payload = "a";
        }
        else{
                $payload = join $payload, $lineRead;
        }
}

close(F);
} # end of the subroutine

if ($options{l}) {
        while (1) { doitall(); }
} else { doitall(); }
exit 0;
```

Comment: *"use Syslog;"* Can you provide a link to this module? I found [Sys::Syslog](https://metacpan.org/pod/Sys::Syslog) on metacpan, but not "Syslog"

Comment: @HåkonHægland - Here's syslog up on Github. https://github.com/CarbonDPG1/WorkBatch/blob/main/Syslog.pm

Comment: Before you do the check `$lineRead eq $check` you should probably [chomp](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp) the line?

Comment: Hey @HåkonHægland - Interesting that you mention that :P. After scratching my head about it I decided to start appending known characters and came across something quite similar.

I ultimately used Regex to remove trailing spaces,new line characters (\r and \n). THen I add a single additional \n to the payload to terminate the sylog message. All appears to be functional now!